# Directory has permissions drw-r--r-- 3 root root ("others" should be able to read it) but I can't cd to it as my user. Why?

Tags: unix, root, file-permissions, system-administration, chown

Isn't this supposed to work? I changed the ownership to that of my user but it still says "Permission denied".

Comment: It is weird to remind this, but... The title is a place in which you define the scope of your question. Then in the question body you ask it properly.

Comment: You need to execute bit set in order to be able to `cd`.  Do `chmod o+x dirname`

Comment: @devnull that was the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to access a directory you need the execution permission on that directory. say chmod o+x /somedir

Hope this helps.